# gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

Tags: ubuntu, gpg

I am trying to install Hexinator on Linux

```
 sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys A04A6C4681484CF1
Executing: /tmp/tmp.jHAVvyUasz/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
keys.gnupg.net
--recv-keys
A04A6C4681484CF1
gpg: requesting key 81484CF1 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

What should I try?I am on Ubuntu 16.04.How to check if firewall is blocking the port?

Comment: @Christopher The same unfortunately,gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

Comment: In my case was a proxy issue, solved setting the environment variables and [`sudo -E`](https://askubuntu.com/a/102505/349837).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably behind a firewall.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net:80 --recv-keys A04A6C4681484CF1
```

It worked for me (I'm behind a firewall. The original one didn't work).

Comment: That's great! I thought my problem was the proxy but this solution fixed my issue!